# Unmanaged descriptor exception using map.clear()

Tags: java, android, exception, google-maps-markers

I have custom infoWindow on an invisible marker.
There is only one marker every time, because as soon as the infoWindow is closed , the marker is removed.

Anyway the following happens: if I leave the infoWindow open and I click on an options item in the toolbar which trigger a `map.clear()` call, in turn this raises the mentioned exception.

I've read that I should keep trace of the markers that are on the map, so I tried to  store a reference to the marker and check if is not null before to call `map.clear()` . If is not `null` the marker is removed and the reference is updated to `null`, anywasy still `map.clear()` invocation produce the exception.

**MapsActivity**

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.connection_type:

            // Creates an alert dialog where the user can choose which connectivity technology to monitor
            final CharSequence connectionsType[] = new CharSequence[]{"GSM", "UMTS", "LTE", "WIFI"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
            builder.setTitle("Choose a wireless technology");
            builder.setItems(connectionsType, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Unregister active connectivity related receiver
                    unregisterProperReceiver(ACTIVE_CONNECTIVITY_TYPE);
                    if(marker != null) {
                        marker.remove();
                        marker = null;

                    }
                    // Clear map
                    mMap.clear();  /* devil is here */
                    ....



 // When the info windows  is closed delete the associated marker
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClose(Marker marker) {
            marker.remove();

        }
    });
```

**Task (just where I set the marker reference)**

```
if (groupedAvgSignalStrength != null && groupedAvgSignalStrength.length != 0 )
        {

            String mgrsTen = groupedAvgSignalStrength[0].mgrsTen;
            String avgSignalStrength = String.valueOf(groupedAvgSignalStrength[0].signalStrength);
            String areaOccurrences = String.valueOf(groupedAvgSignalStrength[0].areaOccurrences);

            InfoWindowData info = new InfoWindowData(mgrsTen,areaOccurrences,avgSignalStrength);

            Marker position = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(location));

            position.setTag(info);

            // Make the marker invisible
            position.setAlpha(0);

            position.showInfoWindow();

            mapsActivity.setMarker(position); /* update marker ref*/

        }
```

**stack trace**

```
10-17 15:31:57.724 17953-17953/com.example.r.lamapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.r.lamapp, PID: 17953
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmanaged descriptor
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366051@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):13)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.q.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366051@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):13)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.dd.q(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366051@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):106)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366051@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):593)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366051@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):301)
        at fq.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14366051@14.3.66 (040408-213742215):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.clear(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.r.lamapp.MapsActivity$4.onClick(MapsActivity.java:594)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1068)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1155)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3133)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4060)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3819)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9941)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2663)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:793)
            at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10161)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4448)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4316)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3916)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3882)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4009)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3890)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4066)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3916)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3882)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3890)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6224)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6198)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6159)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6327)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6298)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6350)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `hideInfoWindow()` method which belongs to the `Marker` class worked.
So when the code executes `hideInfoWindow()` it triggers the `onInfoWindowClose()` callback which in turns remove the marker.

I think that the exception was caused by the fact that I was manually removing the marker (`marker.remove()`) and also implicitly removing it a second time through an invocation to the callback.

Still I don't understand why I didn't get the exception at the second  `marker.remove()` invocation ( it seems more reasonable to me) instead of getting it at `mMap.clear()`.

**MapsActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.connection_type:

            // Creates an alert dialog where the user can choose which connectivity technology to monitor
            final CharSequence connectionsType[] = new CharSequence[]{"GSM", "UMTS", "LTE", "WIFI"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
            builder.setTitle("Choose a wireless technology");
            builder.setItems(connectionsType, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Unregister active connectivity related receiver
                    unregisterProperReceiver(ACTIVE_CONNECTIVITY_TYPE);
                    if(marker != null) {
                        marker.hideInfoWindow();
                        marker = null;
                    }
                    // Clear map
                    mMap.clear();  /* devil is here */
                    ....


 // When the info windows  is closed delete the associated marker
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClose(Marker marker) {
                marker.remove();

            }
        });
```